# how to print to console a single char from a text file using strtok?

Tags: c, text, char, runtime-error

I have a double round list data structure, populated with reservations:

```
struct reservation
{
    unsigned int reservationID;
    char *hotelName;
    unsigned char noRoomsBooked;
    char *clientName;
    char *reservationPeriod;
    float amount;
};

struct listNode
{
    reservation inf;
    listNode *next;
    listNode *prev;
};
```

This is the inseration function:

```
listNode *insertInList(listNode*head, listNode*tail, reservation r)
{
listNode *new= (nodLista*)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
new->inf.reservationId = r.reservationId;
new->inf.hotelName= (char*)malloc((strlen(r.hotelName) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(nou->inf.hotelName, r.hotelName);
new->inf.noRoomsBooked= r.noRoomsBooked;
new->inf.clientName= (char*)malloc((strlen(r.clientName) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(nou->inf.clientName, r.clientName);
new->inf.reservationPeriod= (char*)malloc((strlen(r.reservationPeriod) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(nou->inf.reservationPeriod, r.reservationPeriod);
new->inf.amount= r.amount;  

if (head == NULL)
{
    head = tail = new;
    new->next = head;
    new->prev = head;
}
else
{
    listNode *temp = head;
    while (temp->next != head)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new;
    new->prev = temp;
    new->next = head;
    tail = new;
}
return head;
```

}

I want to populate this list with some date i wrote in a txt file:

This is my txt file:

```
1,Hotel1,2,Client 1,10.05.2017-12.05.2017,200.5
2,Hotel2,1,Client 2,10.06.2017-17.06.2017,100.5
3,Hotel3,3,Client 3,03.03.2017-10.03.2017,800.5
4,Hotel4,2,Client 4,11.04.2017-15.04.2017,300.5
5,Hotel5,1,Client 5,10.05.2016-12.05.2016,150.5
```

And the program to read from file is this:

```
void main()
{
listNode *head= NULL, *tail= NULL;
reservation r;

FILE *f = fopen("Text.txt", "r");

while (!feof(f))
{
    char buffer[200];
    fgets(buffer, 199, f); 
    char *idRezervare = strtok(buffer, ",");
    char *hotelName= strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *noRoomsBooked= strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *clientName= strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *reservationPeriod= strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *amount= strtok(NULL, ",");

    r.reservationID= atoi(reservationID);
    r.hotelName= (char*)malloc((strlen(hotelName) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(r.hotelName, hotelName);
    r.noRoomsBooked= (int)noRoomsBooked;  
    r.clientName= (char*)malloc((strlen(clientName) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(r.clientName, clientName);
    r.reservationPeriod= (char*)malloc((strlen(reservationPeriod) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(r.reservationPeriod, reservationPeriod);
    r.amount= atof(amount);

    head=insertInList(head, tail, r);
}

fclose(f);
printList(head);
```

When I compile in the No of Rooms Booked field it shows me a character(every time I compile, it's another one, and it's similar for all 5 rows).
I guess the error comes from this line:

```
r.noRoomsBooked= (int)noRoomsBooked;
```

But i don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: You need to use `atoi` in a manner similar to your use of `atof`. (i.e.) `r.noRoomsBooked = atoi(noRoomsBooked);`

Comment: @CraigEstey i tried. it dispays the same

Comment: I pulled down your source [and data file] and tried to compile it. As posted, it has a number of compile errors. Since this should be a small enough program, I'd repost your entire/latest/best program [that, at a minimum builds cleanly] as a single file so others can see it and test it locally if they wish

Comment: C++? or C? decide now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reservation::noRoomsBooked` is `unsigned char`, and the variable `noRoomsBooked` is `char*`. You are assigning a pointer without dereferencing it. You just cast the value of the pointer to int, not the value the pointer it points to:

```
r.noRoomsBooked = atoi(noRoomsBooked); // now it works
```

By the way, `unsigned char` is not the best choice in your case. It's reasonable to assume that room number may be greater than 255.

Also, if you are printing this number to a console, remember to cast it to `int` - otherwise you'll get garbage. That's another reason to replace `unsigned char` with an actual integer type. e.g. `unsigned short`.

Comment: You should probably be using atoi as Craig Estey said. Otherwise you're treating the character read from the file as a number. If you debug you will see that for example noRoomsBooked 2 in your text file is 50 in your data structure.

Comment: Right, I've updated the answer. @MihaelaMiki , no problem, you are welcome :)